# How wrap a FormWizard in a View?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-formwizard

How do I wrap a Django [Form Wizard](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/) in a view? I need to do this so I can access `request`.

Does anyone have some example code for this?

Answer (score 5):

I probably should be just commenting on Manoj's answer, but sounds you need code

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from MyApp import views

urlpatterns = patterns(
  '',
  (r'^wizard/$', views.MyWizardView ),
)
```

views.py

```
@login_required    
def MyWizardView (request):
  cw = MyWizard([WizardName, WizardQuestions, WizardProvider, WizardGoomber])
  return cw(request)
```

Comment: I had to change the above to get it to work.  I changed cw=... to cw=MyWizard.as_view([...]). Otherwise it worked nicely

Answer (score 2):

The `as_view` function converts a class based view into a callable view:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.formtools.wizard.views import SessionWizardView

class Form1(forms.Form):
    a = forms.CharField()

class Form2(forms.Form):
    b = forms.CharField()

class MyWizard(SessionWizardView):
    pass

wizard_view = MyWizard.as_view([Form1, Form2])

def view(request):
    # do something fancy with the request object here
    return wizard_view(request)
```

This is basicly the same answer as in [How to wrap a Django Form Wizard in a View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14590759/how-to-wrap-a-django-form-wizard-in-a-view)

Comment: This question is VERY OLD. I just followed a link and saw that it was alsmost the same question without an answer. I did not intend to perform a cadaver dissection.

Comment: Leaving the answer here as it might help the one or another finding the right answer for a newer Django version.

Answer (score 0):

This [Django snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1833/) may prove useful.

From the title: "*FormWizard inside view with proper context handling and site templating support, without having to use urls.py*"

Comment: Well, im lost with "without having to use urls.py"

Comment: This snipped is VERY old. The wizard code has changed a lot since then. Please do not recommend old code examples unless the question specifically asks for a dated Django release.