# How to wrap a Django Form Wizard in a View?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

This question is highly related to one that was previously asked and answered here: [How wrap a FormWizard in a View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503964/how-wrap-a-formwizard-in-a-view)

Can someone post exact details of how they have successfully wrapped a Django Form Wizard into a view so that the login_required decorator can be used? There are numerous discussions of this topic on the internet but they all seem to be incomplete because they don't actually show how they have defined their Form Wizard class.

When I run point my browser to the view, I get the following exception:

```
__init__() takes exactly 1 non-keyword argument (2 given) in views.py line #108
```

What arguments do I pass when I instantiate my Form Wizard object such that it doesn't give me this error?
If you have some sample code that works, please post it.

Here is whats in my urls.py file:

```
url(r'^createObject/$', views.createObjectView, name='createObject'),
```

Here is whats in my views.py file:

```
CREATE_OBJECT_FORMS = [
    ("createMyForm0", createObjectForm0),
    ("createMyForm1", createObjectForm1),
    ("createMyForm2", createObjectForm2),
    ("createMyForm3", createObjectForm3),
]

CREATE_OBJECT_TEMPLATES = {
    "createMyForm0": "myApp/form0.html",
    "createMyForm1": "myApp/form1.html",
    "createMyForm2": "myApp/form2.html",
    "createMyForm3": "myApp/form3.html",
}




@login_required
def createObjectView(request):
    # Set up the dictionary of initial data for the form
    # In this case, we are pre-filling some data from the first form only
    initial = {0: {}}

    # Create the form wizard
    form = createObjectWizard(
        [
            createObjectForm0,
            createObjectForm1,
            createObjectForm2,
            createObjectForm3,
        ], 
        initial=initial      # This is Line #108
    )

    # Call the form wizard passing through the context and the request
    return form(context=RequestContext(request), request=request)    




class createObjectWizard(SessionWizardView):
    def get_template_names(self):
        return [CREATE_OBJECT_TEMPLATES[self.steps.current]]

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        doSomethingFunction(form_list)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/objectCreated/')
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `as_view` function converts a class based view into a callable view:

### myapp/views.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.formtools.wizard.views import SessionWizardView
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse

class Form1(forms.Form):
    a = forms.CharField()

class Form2(forms.Form):
    b = forms.CharField()

FORMS = [("step1", Form1),
         ("step2", Form2)]

TEMPLATES = {"step1": "wizard_step.html",
             "step2": "wizard_step.html"}

class MyWizard(SessionWizardView):

    def get_template_names(self):
        return [TEMPLATES[self.steps.current]]

    def done(self, form_list):
        # get data from forms
        a = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('step1')['a']
        b = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('step2')['b']
        # access the request as self.request
        request = self.request
        # (...)
        # return response
        return TemplateResponse(request, 'wizard_success.html', {
            'a': a,
            'b': a
        })

wizard_view = MyWizard.as_view(FORMS)

@require_login
def wrapped_wizard_view(request):
    return wizard_view(request)
```

### myapp/templates/wizard_step.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block content %}

<form method="post">
{% include "formtools/wizard/wizard_form.html" %}
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

### myapp/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns('myapp.views',
    url(r'^wizard/$', 'wrapped_wizard_view'),
)
```

Comment: I can't put my finger on it, but it feels somehow kludgy to put the login_required() call right into the urls.py file. Is my concern valid?

Comment: I do not like the use of decorators in the urls.py either, but it is one way as described in the Django docs: [class-based-views#decorating-class-based-views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/#decorating-class-based-views)

Comment: Your example above doesn't advance between the two forms after I click submit on the first one. Can you show how to modify the MyWizard class to do this and also to specify a different template for each step of the form?

Comment: I just reworked the example code. It does now include all the bits you need to use a SessionFormWizard. This answer no longer only answers your original question but also shows how to use the wizards in general.

Comment: I have added a function done(self, form_list, **kwargs) to your MyWizard class. In that function, I need to access the user's ID. The user's ID is available in wrapped_wizard_view by doing request.user.id. How can I pass that value through the Form Wizard so that it is accessible from inside the done() function?

Comment: You can access the request object from inside the `done` function as: `self.request`

Comment: I just added a done method to my example. If there is still anything unclear please raise a new question.

Comment: Works perfectly and so easy! I had no idea that from within the form wizard I could access the request by simply doing self.request. Thanks so much!

Comment: @user1742777 If it works then why don't you accept the answer and mark this question solved?

Comment: @bikeshedder: It seems like you know a lot about `FormWizards`. I am having trouble getting initial data for my wizard so that users can edit their objects. I made a [StackOverflow Question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14942686/edit-django-formwizard-getting-initial-data) but it has not gotten many comments yet. If you have any ideas how to solve my problem I would greatly appreciate the help! Thanks for your intellectual contributions to the programming community.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative answer - instead of wrapping your view you could always use a decorator on your `Wizardview` class, [as described in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class)

You would therefore do the following imports:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
```

and then within `class createObjectWizard(SessionWizardView)` you would add the following:

```
 @method_decorator(login_required)
 def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
     return super(createObjectWizard, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

this way you don't have to mess with `urls.py` - it's all taken care of within the view.
Hope this helps