# Edit Django Formwizard: Getting Initial Data

Tags: django, edit, wizard

I am trying to edit existing objects using my Django FormWizard. I am following the technique described in [this blog post](http://ten.ynottony.net/2011/01/using-django-formwizard-in-a-view/), but it does not work. Here is my edit view:

```
@login_required
def edit_wizard(request, id):
    thing = get_object_or_404(Thing, pk=id)
    if thing.user != request.user:
        raise HttpResponseForbidden()
    else:
        initial = {0: {'year': thing.year,
                       'make': thing.make,
                       'series': thing.series,
                        ....etc.
                       },
                   1: {'condition': thing.condition,
                        ....etc.
                       },
                   }

     form = CreateWizard.as_view([StepOneForm, StepTwoForm, StepThreeForm], initial_dict=initial)
     return form(context=RequestContext(request), request=request)
```

Can you help me figure out how to provide the initial data to the Wizard so that I can allow users to edit their objects? Thanks for your ideas!

---

EDIT: (2/18/13)

Was getting a:

```
TypeError at /edit/10/   __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
```

This was solved by @sneawo's answer below, but still no initial data is passed, and the wizard instead creates new objects.

---

EDIT: (2/19/13)

```
class CreateWizard(SessionWizardView):
    file_storage = FileSystemStorage(location=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT))
    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        instance = Thing()
        for form in form_list:
            for field, value in form.cleaned_data.iteritems():
                setattr(instance, field, value)
        instance.user = self.request.user
        instance.save()
        return render_to_response('wizard-done.html', {
            'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],
        })
```

Comment: Why you use `thing = Thing(user=request.user)` in `else` condition?

Comment: Oh yeh. My mistake. Removed that condition, however, now have a `TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)`. Added details above. Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Could you also show the code for `CreateWizard` class.

Comment: @sneawo: Added the `CreateWizard`. Thanks for any ideas..

Comment: Thanks to @sneawo the `TypeError` is now gone (+1 thank you), however I am still not able to get the initial data to the form so that I can edit objects. Instead, for some reason a new object is created when I use the `edit_wizard` view described above. Any ideas from the community are really appreciated to try to conquer this FormWizard issue. Thank you!

Comment: As I see it's in your `done` method - `instance = Thing()`. I think you can try to add attribute `instance = None` into `class CreateWizard` and pass `thing` in `return form(context=RequestContext(request), request=request, instance=thing)`

Comment: Thanks for the ideas @sneawo. However, setting `instance = None` in my FormWizard class and passing `instance=thing` in my return does not populate the form with the instance. Sorry that this is so difficult for both of us. I had no idea that creating a FormWizard would be so difficult, but I appreciate your help and ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the documentation, for Django 1.4+ you pass the initial data in **initial_dict** keyword argument. For previous versions(1.3, it seems it wasn't there before 1.3) the keyword argument was **initial**.  Also, the keys for steps in your initial data dict should be strings not integers.

```
initial = {'0': {'year': thing.year,
                 'make': thing.make,
                 'series': thing.series,
                  ....etc.
                },
           '1': {'condition': thing.condition,
                  ....etc.
                },
          }
```

**UPDATE**:
To update the same object you have to set the id also, otherwise there is no way for django to know which object to update. A simple way to do it is to pass the id in a hidden field, but you have to do the user permission check again in your (done) method.

```
initial = {0: {'id': thing.id,


class CreateWizard(SessionWizardView):
    file_storage = FileSystemStorage(location=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT))
    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
       id = form_list[0].cleaned_data['id']
       thing = get_object_or_404(Thing, pk=id)
       if thing.user != self.request.user:
           raise HttpResponseForbidden()
       else:
         instance = Thing()
         for form in form_list:
             for field, value in form.cleaned_data.iteritems():
                 setattr(instance, field, value)
         instance.user = self.request.user
         instance.save()
         return render_to_response('wizard-done.html', {
             'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],})
```

and of course StepOneForm should have id with hidden field:

```
class StepOneForm(forms.Form):
    id = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)
```

Comment: Thank you @almalki. Setting the initial data dict to strings has allowed me to get the `initial_dict` into the form. However, a new instance is created instead of modifying the original instance. Can you help me understand why? Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for your help @almalki (+1)! The only problem left is `global name 'request' is not defined` at line `return form` in my view. I'm not sure how to properly return the information.. Do you have any ideas how to return the form? I really appreciate you sharing your knowledge. Thank you!

Comment: @NickB it was working, right? you might broke something while changing. at which step (view)  this exception is happening?

Comment: Thanks @almalki. I have been able to get the `initial_data` into the form, but I have not been able to edit the instance correctly because of this line: `return form(context=RequestContext(request), request=request)`. The error is `global name 'request' is not defined` in my view `edit_wizard`. The error occurs when trying to submit the form to update the object. This seems to be the only thing preventing me from updating the object. Do you have any ideas that can help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: @NickB I am really confused here, if 'edit_wizard' is the first view and there was an exception, how did you get the form with initial data?

Comment: Thanks @almalki. I guess cause the function hasn't needed to return anything until that point? Although I'm not quite sure myself... The code I am using is your `class CreateWizard` and my view `edit_wizard`. The initial data is there, but trying to submit my form and update the instance gives `NameError: global name request is not defined`. If you look at the blog post I linked above that is the basis for the view function I was trying to create. Im not sure why there is an error but I am positive that the code I am using is as stated. I am using Django 1.4.2. I really appreciate your ideas!

Comment: @NickB omg, my mistake, it should be self.request, see updated CreateWizard

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much for your help @almalki. Really insightful and helpful.

Comment: I have just realized that this method does not allow for new objects to be created. Is there any way to use `get_or_create` rather than `get_object_or_404`?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `form = CreateWizard.as_view([StepOneForm, StepTwoForm, StepThreeForm], initial=initial)`