# Use get_or_create Django

Tags: django, forms, django-formwizard

This is a continuation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14942686/edit-django-formwizard-getting-initial-data).

The problem is that the code does not allow for creating new objects because of `thing = get_object_or_404(Thing, pk=id)`

```
class CreateWizard(SessionWizardView):
    file_storage = FileSystemStorage(location=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT))
    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
       id = form_list[0].cleaned_data['id']
       thing = get_object_or_404(Thing, pk=id)
       if thing.user != self.request.user:
           raise HttpResponseForbidden()
       else:
           instance = Thing()
           for form in form_list:
               for field, value in form.cleaned_data.iteritems():
                   setattr(instance, field, value)
           instance.user = self.request.user
           instance.save()
           return render_to_response('wizard-done.html', {
               'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],})
```

How can I use `get_or_create` with this function? Or is there another, better way to create new objects within this function? Thanks for your ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it would be:

```
class CreateWizard(SessionWizardView):
    file_storage = FileSystemStorage(location=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT))

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):

       id = form_list[0].cleaned_data['id']

       try:
           thing = Thing.objects.get(pk=id)
           instance = thing
       except:
           thing = None
           instance = None

       if thing and thing.user != self.request.user:
           raise HttpResponseForbidden()

       if not thing:
           instance = Thing()
           for form in form_list:
               for field, value in form.cleaned_data.iteritems():
                   setattr(instance, field, value)
           instance.user = self.request.user
           instance.save()

       return render_to_response('wizard-done.html', {
               'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],})
```